# Jhipster gradle build not loading production profile

Tags: java, build, gradle, jhipster

I'm new to Jhipster application and just giving it a shot. I am unable to build project with Production profile. Below is the command I invoked. I see it does load the "profile_prod.gradle" file but does not go inside the following block:

```
task setProdProperties(dependsOn: bootRun) << {
    doFirst {
        println "Not getting here"
        System.setProperty('spring.profiles.active', 'prod')
    }
}
```

Gradle command I invoked:

```
gradle -Pprofile=prod clean build
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no `doFirst` block in `doLast` (`<<`) action. Instead try:

```
task setProdProperties(dependsOn: bootRun) {
    doFirst {
        println "Not getting here"
        System.setProperty('spring.profiles.active', 'prod')
    }
}
```

and invoke the command once again.